# facebook api which notifies the unfriend

Tags: facebook

I am working on some project that needs that when ever a friend of mine unfriends me from his list I gets notified so that I update the list of my friend list, one way of doing it is I can schedule a cron job and that will update my friend list once or twice in a day in my project, but that is not going to be real time, I searched the internet but did not finds any thing in fact may be I am struggling with some different keywords and may be that particular thing is termed differently, please shed some light since I am new in facebook api thing I am struggling with the internet false posts as well.

Thanks in advance 
Ankur

Comment: Such an app would be explicitly against facebook's policies and would be shut down if noticed - also, the cron-based method you have already is probably the only way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in @Igy's comment, what you are asking for is exactly what Facebook is highlighting as a "[Prohibited Functionality](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Prohibited_Functionality/)":

> **Revealing Friend Removals**
>   You must not include features or functionality that disregards or circumvents Facebook product
>   limitations. For example, you must **not** notify a user if someone
>   removes the user as a friend because Facebook does not publish this
>   information to users